# App Service in ASE with dot in URL returns 404

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api2, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I'm facing an issue with an App Service in an Azure App Service Environment (ASE) v2 with Web API 2 / .NET 4.7:
The Request URI contains a dot in the last URI fragment and the endpoint returns a 404 when being called.

In the dev environment locally I have been able to fix this by changing the web.config like this:

```xml
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="ApiURIs-ISAPI-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="WebDAV" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0"
           path="*"
           verb="*"
           type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler"
           preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
      <add name="ApiURIs-ISAPI-Integrated-4.0"
           path="*"
           verb="*"
           type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler"
           preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
  </system.webServer>
```

The change has been to add the `ApiURIs-ISAPI-Integrated-4.0`-Handler.

As said, this works fine locally but when being deployed to the ASE App Service, this seems to be ignored and I still get a 404.

Currently, as a workaround, I'm adding a trailing `/` to the URI but I have to get this fixed for prod.

Comment: Did you get to solve this? I'm also facing the same issue with a dot in the last uri fragment

Comment: This also happens these days. Any solution?

Comment: Didn't solve it and it's unlikely I will as I don't use Azure any longer.